# SQL Row aggregation

Tags: sql-server

Sample data:

```
Id  User    Value
1   A       X=1
1   A       Y=2
1   A       X=1
1   A       X=1
1   A       Y=2
1   A       X=1
1   A       Y=2
1   A       X=0
1   A       NULL
1   A       NULL
```

I have a dataset as described in Picture I want to group them based on Id,User each value seperated by 'OR'. for E.g (X=1) OR (Y=2) OR .....

i found i can use string_agg() but it is available only in sql server 17 but i am using sql server 2014. Any Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like

```
SELECT ID,
       [User],
       STUFF(
             (
               SELECT ' OR ' + '(' + Value + ')'
               FROM T T2
               WHERE T2.ID = T1.ID
               FOR XML PATH('')
             ), 1, 4, ''
       ) Result
FROM T T1
GROUP BY ID, [User];
```